# Show only values with more than 0 in chart

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a chart who I pupulate like this:

```
        hardSpecChart.DataSource = hardSpecModel;
        hardSpecChart.Series.First().XValueMember = "TasksName";
        hardSpecChart.Series.First().YValueMembers = "Time";
```

Problem is somethimes my `Y` values come with `0`, so I don't want to show label of that items in chart, so to fix it I just do

```
   hardSpecChart.DataSource = hardSpecModel.Where(x => x.Time > 0);
```

It works, but no as spected, I want to dissapear only labels from chart but not value at the top left of chart:

[image]

I want to show all labels at the top right of chart but I don't want to show at the graphic if they have value 0

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can instead simply use a Format the supresses `0` values. Is it a Pie chart? Do show the whole chart, please!

Comment: Yes is a pie chart I update my question with complete chart, how can I supress 0? @TaW

Comment: I have added an answer with an example; curious: What are the 1st three legend items?? Did you add those in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Pie chart some extra rules apply:

- Only the Y-values matter. (But if you add X-Values you can still refer to them in expressions, see below..)
- You can have several Series but only Points from the 1st one show in the chart. Those from additional series do show in the Legend, though.
- By default the `Legend` shows each Y-Value, not the Series name,
- As usual the Legend can be influenced by properties `LegendText` and `IsVisibleInLegend`, both of which can be applied to either the whole Series or individual DataPoints.
- DataPoints are shown as slices with a width (angle) proportional to their values compared to the sum of all absolute values; see the image below! **This implies that points with a value of `0` do not show at all.**
- But: If you set `IsValueShownAsLabel` to `true`, **zero-value labels still will show as `0`.**

To suppress those you can either

- change that property for points that are `0` by looping over the points (ugly) or..
- set a `LabelFormat` that suppresses the `0` for the whole series: `someseries.LabelFormat = "#";`

In the chart below I have set

```
chart1.Series[0].LabelFormat = "#";
chart1.Series[0].LegendText = "#INDEX. = #VAL";
```

There are many other [keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/dd456687(v=vs.100)), which can also be combined..

[image]